# GPA array calculation error

Tags: java

I am having issues with my gpa program where I have to use two arrays to store a grade and it's credits and calculate the gpa.  So far, everything else seems to be working except the gpa wont calculate correctly and I am not sure what I am missing (probably simple).

My code thus far is:

Gpa class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Gpa{

      int[] credits = new int[4];
      String[] grades = new String[4];

      private int numCourses;
      private int maxCourses;
      private int sumOfCourses;
      private int sumCredits;
      private int sumPoints;
      int newCredits;
      int totalSum = 0;
      int total = 0;


      public Gpa(int noCourses){
        maxCourses = noCourses;
        numCourses = 0; 


      }

      public void addCourse(int _newCredits, String newGrade){
         for (int i=0; i<maxCourses; i++){
           newCredits = _newCredits;
           credits[i] = newCredits;
         }
         for (int i=0; i<maxCourses; i++){
            grades[i] = newGrade;
         }
            switch (newGrade) {
               case "A":
               case "a":
                  newGrade = "4";
                  break;
               case "B":
               case "b":
                  newGrade = "3";
                  break;
               case "C":
               case "c":
                  newGrade = "2";
                  break;
               case "D":
               case "d":
                  newGrade = "1";
                  break;
               case "F":
               case "f":
                  newGrade = "0";
                  break;
              }
          sumPoints = sumPoints + (newCredits * Integer.parseInt(newGrade));
          numCourses++;

      }

      public double calcGPA(){
         for (int i=0; i<maxCourses; i++){
            sumCredits = sumCredits + newCredits;
         }
         double gpa = (double)sumPoints/sumCredits;
         return gpa;
      }


















} // end class
```

The tester class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GpaTestEx2
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        //declarations
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //input object
        int numCourses; //number of courses - can be changed
        int credits;        //number of credits for a course
        String grade;       //grade for course


        //read in number of courses
        System.out.print("Enter number of courses: ");
        numCourses = in.nextInt();

        //create Gpa object to hold specified number of courses
        Gpa myGPA = new Gpa(numCourses);

        //read in all courses and add course information to Gpa object
        for (int k=0; k<numCourses; k++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter credits for course " + (k+1) + ": ");
            credits = in.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter grade for course " + (k+1) + ": ");
            grade = in.next();

            myGPA.addCourse(credits, grade);
        }

        //print results
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("GPA is %4.2f%n", myGPA.calcGPA( )); 

    } //end main
}
```

When I enter the course credits and grade it does not calculate the gpa correctly. For example, if the user input says there are 2 courses with one class having 4 credits with a grade of A and the other having 3 credits with a grade of B.  I get a gpa of around 4.17 when it should be 3.57.

Any help would be great, I may or may not be missing something simple.

Comment: why in the `addCourse` are you setting every element of the array to the newly entered grade? Perhaps I am missing something in the logic, but it seems like you would want to only set the latest entry in the array. And use a local variable for the points as an int rather than setting to a String and then parsing the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are indexing into every element in your array every time someone inserts a value. We only need to change one element when a new grade is added. GPA class:

```
public class Gpa {

    private int[] credits;
    private String[] grades;
    private int currentGrade;

    public Gpa(int numGrades) {
        credits = new int[numGrades];
        grades = new String[numGrades];
        currentGrade = 0;
    }

    public void addGrade(String letterGrade, int credit) {
        grades[currentGrade] = letterGrade;
        credits[currentGrade] = credit;
        currentGrade = currentGrade + 1;
    }

    public double getGpa() {
        double totalPoints = 0;
        double totalWeight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < currentGrade; i++) {
            totalPoints = totalPoints + (letterToGpa(grades[i]) * credits[i]);
            totalWeight = totalWeight + credits[i];
        }

        return totalPoints / totalWeight;
    }

    private double letterToGpa(String letter) {
        char first = letter.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        switch (first) {
            case 'A':
                return 4.0;
            case 'B':
                return 3.0;
            case 'C':
                return 2.0;
            case 'D':
                return 1.0;
        }
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

The test class should work fine now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //input object
    int numCourses; //number of courses - can be changed
    int credits;        //number of credits for a course
    String grade;       //grade for course

    //read in number of courses
    System.out.print("Enter number of courses: ");
    numCourses = in.nextInt();

    //create Gpa object to hold specified number of courses
    Gpa t = new Gpa(numCourses);

    //read in all courses and add course information to Gpa object
    for (int k=0; k<numCourses; k++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter credits for course " + (k+1) + ": ");
        credits = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter grade for course " + (k+1) + ": ");
        grade = in.next();

        t.addGrade(grade, credits);
    }

    //print results
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("GPA is %4.2f%n", t.getGpa()); 
}
```

Just want to note that this clearly isn't the best way of doing this, nor does it follow Object Oriented patterns very well, but the OP's assignment requires we only use one class, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm supposed to keep it at just GPA class and the tester

Comment: @BrianAndris That's fine - you can easily combine them. Should I edit my answer to show that?

Comment: if you wouldn't mind,  in the mean time ill look over what it is and try to see what I can do.

Comment: @BrianAndris see my edit. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I am required to use the two arrays in my assignment.

Comment: @BrianAndris Edited one last time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it working thanks to your help.  I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @BrianAndris Happy to help. Enjoy your evening.